# How to make visible an object from different layer in bge

Tags: python, game-engine, layers

I want to give a model a selection circle if (and only if) it is clicked once or twice. The circle is in another layer and i want to make it visible when i click on my model, and invisible when i click on the ground, and toggle those states

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a way to do what you want; but there's a better way! I recommend the `Visibility` sensor.

Assuming one object is called `Circle`, the other one `Character` and the other `Ground`, start by moving the `Circle` to the main layer; Then, in the `Outliner`, disable it's render-ability, by pressing the camera icon next to it.

After that, select your `Character` and add a *Message* actuator to it; Set the `To:` field to be `Circle`, and the `Subject` field to be *`Set Visible`*. Then, select the `Ground` add another `Message` actuator, with the `To:` field set to `Circle` and the `Subject` set to  *`Set Invisible`*.

[image]

Then select the `Circle` and add two *Message sensors* to it; set their subjects to be the same as previously, and connect each to a *`Visibility`* actuator, set to either set visible or invisible, depending on the message subject.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!! Your idea works half, if i open the game the circle isn't visible, if i click on the model if its visible. But if i click on the ground, THE CIRCLE REMAINS VISIBLE! Any way to fix that? Thank you for early sunday reply :)

Comment: Problem solved! I added a invisibility message to ground set to circle!!!

Comment: @GonzaloGómezFernández Glad I helped :D
I would appreciate it if you accepted and/or upvoted my answer, BTW.

Comment: I would do, if i knew how to do!! I am noob to this page. Tell me how i can give you a good amount of votes